# refreshing a php page with a new url, drawn from a curl output

Tags: php, forms, url, curl

i have a form, which upon submission needs to refresh the page with a new url.

the new url however needs to come from the output of a curl function.

at the moment, I can get the curl function to operate correctly, but instead of refreshing the page with that url, it is just printing the url on the page.

have you any idea how i could use that url to refresh the page with?

thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://uk.ImpulsePay.com/payforit?RouteID=5432&URL=Y"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);   


header( "Location: curl_exec($ch)");
curl_close($ch);
```

If you visit the link above - it will display a page which has a link in the body. I am assentially trying to get the link in the body of the page, and then refresh the page to that page.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think you need curl at all if I understand correct. Please post your code so we can get a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: hi, i do need to use curl, because basically the url that i submit to curl spits out a new url, and that is the url that the page needs to refresh to. it is a payment processing thing so i guess it is for some reason they ask you to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the PHP header() method, see this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Here's their example:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
```

Take note of the line that reads:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent

If you need to change the header after some content has already been "printed" you'll need to use output buffering, see this page to get started: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

UPDATE:
Your curl_exec( $ch ) is not executing because you can't execute functionality inside of double quotes, you can only insert variables.

Here's what you want to do:

```
$httpResponse = curl_exec( $ch );
header( "Location: $httpResponse");
```

Assuming that the response is just a URL, this will redirect your user's browser to the value returned by your curl request.

UPDATE:
I missed that you do not have a return transfer setting.
You will need to add this line after your `CURLOPT_HEADER` line:

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
```

This will tell curl_exec to return the response instead of a boolean success indication.

See the "Return values" section at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: can i put code in front of the php header method? and just not anything that needs to be output? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can, as long as there's nothing before the php opening **<?php** and none of your lines of code echo/print anything. Otherwise you'll need to use the output buffering as mentioned.

Comment: Ok great...and is there a way that I can take the output of a curl function and use that as the url to refresh the header to?

Comment: Go ahead and post the code you're using for the curl request so it'll be easier to make suggestions for you.

Comment: hi, that still doesnt work still, it is refreshing my page to http://mydomain.com/payment-form/1 as opposed to the intended address.

any thoughts as to why? if you run the code without the heading tags around the curl_exec( $ch ) part it outputs a domain name so not sure why it is just putting 1 on the end of my domain

Comment: Tell me what you see if you do this: echo "-".curl_exec( $ch )."-"; Without the header() line.

Comment: http://uk.ImpulsePay.com/r2ctuj-1-  (where everything before the -1- is the domain which i want the page to be redirected to)

Comment: Ok, I think we're miscommunicating here. The dashes in what you have shown me are just around the 1. This means that the curl_exec is simply returning a 1, or in other words boolean true, meaning it's likely telling  you that it was successful. I'm not sure how you're getting that URL in there before the -1-. Unless you're concatenating something else. This should probably be a new question at this point.

Comment: hi, i thought that myself - but then if i run it with just curl_exec( $ch ); and not the echo, it shoots out the domain. however in this same scenario if i remove the curl_exec( $ch ); altogether the domain does not appear on the page, so surely it must be the cause of the domain being there?

Comment: See my update, I overlooked something that I typically just put in as an afterthought, but it's what makes your response accessible via curl_exec().